# PHP mysql_affected_rows() Should I Care?

Tags: php, mysql

I have always struggled with a fairly basic concept in my PHP INSERT/UPDATE code. Should I always be checking for the number of affected rows after every INSERT/UPDATE because in the vast majority of times I am only ever performing one INSERT/UPDATE and it seems to cause more problems than it fixes by checking that only one row was affected.

Below is my standard code to perform the INSERT/UPDATE and this code fails if the user is updating a record without changing anything because the affected rows will be 0. I could write code to check that at least one field has changed but on large forms this seems very clunky and was wondering if it is really worth it because I have never really ever caught any errors by checking this number anyway.

```
<?php
        $whereSql = '';
        $groupSql = 'INSERT INTO';

        if(isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id'])){
            $groupSql = 'UPDATE';
            $whereSql = 'WHERE id = ' . $_POST['id'];
        }

        $groupSql .= ' sometable SET name="' . $name . '" ' . $whereSql;

        $groupDb = mysqli_query($groupSql, $dbObject) or die("Login DB error:".mysql_error());

        if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbObject) == 1){
            //redirect
        }else{
            die('System Error');
        }
```

Comment: -0.49 for using `mysql_query` in 2013.

Comment: why not printing error if mysql_affected_rows($dbObject) == -1. From manual -> Returns the number of affected rows on success, and -1 if the last query failed.

Comment: @cHao this is legacy code

Comment: @TheoKouzelis: Then don't screw around with it.  It obviously works.

Comment: @cHao if you read the question it doesn't

Comment: @TheoKouzelis: So you have to change it anyway.  Make up your mind.  :P

Comment: @cHao I just don't get the down vote for mysql functions?

Comment: @TheoKouzelis: It's less than half a downvote, which rounds to 0.  Relax, you haven't lost your 2 points yet.  :P  But i'm tired of people thinking that they can get away with still using (and expecting help with) ext/mysql after it's been officially deprecated.

Comment: @cHao lol ok its only half a down vote but still I think mysql functions are still relevant because there will still be lots of servers still not supporting mysqli

Comment: They either support ext/mysqli or PDO, or they should be put out of their misery.  There is no good excuse for having ext/mysql but not at least one of those two.

Comment: @cHao I stand firmly corrected and I have edited my code to make my question more relevant for future generations. :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be checking return values on queries. A select/update query which affects/returns no rows is **NOT** an error condition, it's simply an empty result set, or an update which happened to affect nothing.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Consider a user signup system which checks for the existence of a matching username:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='foo';
```

if the user `foo` does not exist, your system will barf and claim an error occurred. But an empty result set is **NOT** an error. It simply means the username is available for user.

Same for a system that handles grades:

```
UPDATE students SET failed=true WHERE score < 50;
```

getting 0 affected rows is NOT a failure. It just means all the students passed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking if the query has failed, and if not, then if there was more than one row affected.

```
$groupDb = mysql_query($groupSql, $dbObject);
if (false === $groupDb) {
    die("Login DB error:".mysql_error())
if (mysql_affected_rows($dbObject) > 1) {
    die('System Error: failed to ' . $action . ' a  document Group');
} else {
    //redirect
}
```

This way you will redirect only in case of successful queries and if there was less than 2 rows affected (if that is important to you).